# ORACLE SQL: I've got a crude solution to a problem using LEAD and CASE WHEN but would like a more elegant solution

Tags: loops, sql-update, iteration, oracle-sqldeveloper

Goal: Given a table of patient records that show entry and exit dates per facility, I want to find the Original_entrydate for each record in the table.

Consider this table, which is sorted by entry_date descending and grouped by ID:

| ID | Facility | entry_date | exit_date | original_entrydate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 003246 | C | 2022-03-22 | null | **2012-10-01** |
| 003246 | B | 2015-07-24 | *2022-03-22 (matches row 1 entry_date)* | **2012-10-01** |
| 003246 | A | **2012-10-01** | *2015-07-24 (matches row 2 entry_date)* | **2012-10-01** |
| 003246 | D | 2001-02-02 | *2010-04-05 (does NOT match row 3 entry_date!)* | 2001-02-02 |

Starting from the earliest record, Patient #003246

- Entered Facility D on 2/2/2001 and left on 4/5/2010.
- Entered Facility A on 10/1/2012 and left on **7/24/2015** - so there was a gap in service between 2010 & 2012.
- Entered Facility B on **7/24/2015** and left on *3/22/2022*
- Entered Facility C on *3/22/2022* and remains there today.

As you can see, when the individual entered Facility A, there has been **no gap in service** between 10/1/2012 and today--even though the patient switched facilities, they have been a resident since 10/1/2012--**therefore 10/1/2012 is the original_entrydate for the first three records in the table,** but not the 4th record, since there was a gap in service between Facilities D and A.

I managed to write a query that gave me what I want, but it's extremely clunky and will fail if a resident appears more than 4 times in the table (because my LEADs only go 4 rows deep--sufficient for my test table but not necessarily for the actual data).

```
SELECT 
    t1.resident_key,
    t1.lidda, 
    t1.facility_key, 
    t1.admit_dt_key,
    t1.separation_dt_key,
    CASE
        WHEN prev_sep1 IS NULL
        THEN admit_dt_key
        WHEN admit_dt_key != prev_sep1
        THEN admit_dt_key
        WHEN admit_dt_key = prev_sep1
        THEN CASE 
                WHEN prev_sep2 IS NULL
                THEN prev_admit1
                WHEN prev_admit1 != prev_sep2
                THEN prev_admit1
                WHEN prev_admit1 = prev_sep2
                THEN CASE
                        WHEN prev_sep3 IS NULL
                        THEN prev_admit2
                        WHEN prev_admit2 != prev_sep3
                        THEN prev_admit2
                        WHEN prev_admit2 = prev_sep3
                        THEN CASE
                                WHEN prev_sep4 IS NULL
                                THEN prev_admit3
                                WHEN prev_admit3 != prev_sep4
                                THEN prev_admit3
                            END
                    END
            END
    END
    as Original_AdmDt 

 FROM
        (SELECT my_table.*,
            LEAD (separation_dt_key, 1) OVER (
                                PARTITION BY resident_key
                                ORDER BY admit_dt_key DESC
            ) prev_sep1, 
            LEAD (admit_dt_key, 1) OVER (
                                PARTITION BY resident_key
                                ORDER BY admit_dt_key DESC
            ) prev_admit1,
            LEAD (separation_dt_key, 2) OVER (
                                PARTITION BY resident_key
                                ORDER BY admit_dt_key DESC
            ) prev_sep2, 
            LEAD (admit_dt_key, 2) OVER (
                                PARTITION BY resident_key
                                ORDER BY admit_dt_key DESC
            ) prev_admit2,
            LEAD (separation_dt_key, 3) OVER (
                                PARTITION BY resident_key
                                ORDER BY admit_dt_key DESC
            ) prev_sep3, 
            LEAD (admit_dt_key, 3) OVER (
                                PARTITION BY resident_key
                                ORDER BY admit_dt_key DESC
            ) prev_admit3,
            LEAD (separation_dt_key, 4) OVER (
                                PARTITION BY resident_key
                                ORDER BY admit_dt_key DESC
            ) prev_sep4, 
            LEAD (admit_dt_key, 4) OVER (
                                PARTITION BY resident_key
                                ORDER BY admit_dt_key DESC
            ) prev_admit4
        FROM my_table) t1
```

Can I make this iterative, to deal with however many times a unique ID may appear in the table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.date1, t2.date2, 
       CASE 
          WHEN t1.date1 < t2.date2 THEN t1.date1 
          ELSE t2.date2 
       END AS result 
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table1 t2 
ON t1.id < t2.id 
WHERE t1.date1 < t2.date2 
ORDER BY t1.id, t2.id;
```

Comment: For each row, I need to find the original_entrydate, moving back through time until a gap between entry_date and previous separation_date is found, and then take that admit_date just after the gap and populate the original_entrydate column with it. This logic doesn't get me there, though I hadn't thought of comparing dates with a self-join, and that may help.